# Issue with RewriteCond

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, apache2

Ive got an issue with apache's rewrite module. This is what im trying to do:

Ive got confluence(tomcat) running on a server with apache as reverse proxy in front.
Also, im using authentification in apache (form auth). So if ure trying to access [server]/confluence, you get redirected to a file login.php containing the authentification routine. If login succeeds, proxy lets u access tomcat.
Every other request is blocked. This works easily for every request except for [server]/login.php as this file exists indeed in htdocs. Every other request is handled with

```
FallbackResource wrong_url.shtml
```

Now i want to block direct access to login.php as you would get stuck in a dead end.

I tried to do this by using a RewriteCond with ${REQUEST_URI} as phpinfo() gave me this:

```
<server>/confluence (you automatically get redirected to login.php by apache): php says REQUEST_URI = /confluence

<server>/login.php:   php says REQUEST_URI = /login.php
```

makes sense, though. Now what i did is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 192.168.2.237
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/login.php$
    RewriteRule ^/login.php$  wrong_url.shtml [L]

</VirtualHost>
```

But this doesnt work properly. It either wont work at all or it crashes everything.
Pls forgive me if this is obvious, but im quite a beginner to rewriting. Can anybody tell me wheres my fault oder provide me a way to do this (propably, this is really easy)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the server logs ? Enable and set RewriteLogLevel (to 9) and debug the request flow.

Although you don't really need mod_rewrite for such a basic task, use mod_alias instead.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 192.168.2.237
    Alias /login.php /wrong_url.shtml
</VirtualHost>
```